# Django ChoiceField get currently selected

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms

I have a simple ChoiceField and want to access the 'selected' item during my template rendering.

Lets say the form gets show again (due to error in one of the fields), is there a way to do something like:

```
<h1> The options you selected before was # {{ MyForm.delivery_method.selected }} </h1>
```

(.selected() is not working..)

Thanks !

Comment: If you re-render the form in the normal way as shown in the documentation, all the fields should have their previous values, including the select fields. If this isn't happening, you need to show your code so we can tell where you're going wrong.

Comment: I am using a custom method to show the form as I need various special fields added for AJAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be accessed by `{{ myform.delivery_method.data }}`

```
<h1> The options you selected before was # {{ MyForm.delivery_method.data }} </h1>
```

Comment: For more recent Django versions, it's .value instead of .data.

Answer (score 5):

@Yuji suggested `bund_choice_field.data`, however that will return value which is not visible to user (used in `value="backend-value"`). In your situation you probably want literal value visible to user (`<option>literal value</option>`). I think there is no easy way to get literal value from choice field in template. So I  use template filter which does that:

```
@register.filter(name='choiceval')
def choiceval(boundfield):
    """ 
    Get literal value from field's choices. Empty value is returned if value is 
    not selected or invalid.

    Important: choices values must be unicode strings.

        choices=[(u'1', 'One'), (u'2', 'Two')
    """
    value = boundfield.data or None
    if value is None:
        return u''
    return dict(boundfield.field.choices).get(value, u'')
```

In template it will look like this:

```
<h1> The options you selected before was # {{ form.delivery_method|choiceval }} </h1>
```

UPDATE: I forgot to mention an important thing, that you will need to use unicode in choice values. This is because data returned from form is always in unicode. So `dict(choices).get(value)` wont work if integers where used in choices.