# Django: Rendering display value of a ModelChoiceField and ChoiceField in a template

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a `ModelChoiceField` and a `ChoiceField` that I need to pull out the "display name" for (not the "value").

For example, a `ModelChoiceField` of a form renders the following output:

```
<select name="amodelfield" id="id_amodelfield">
<option value="">---------</option>
<option selected="selected" value="1">ABC</option>
<option value="2">DEF</option>
</select>
```

I want to be able to just render "**ABC**" since it is selected. If I do `{{ field.value }}` as said in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/), I get the value `1` instead of the `ABC` I wanted. I also have a ChoiceField for which I want the same behavior.

Is there a easy way to do this without subclassing `ModelChoiceField`, `ChoiceField` and the `Select` widget?

EDIT: `Model.get_FOO_display()` would not work in this case

Answer (score 3):

Use {{ get_fieldname_display }} for it.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display

Comment: This does not work because 1) I do not know the name of the field ahead of time 2) How do you get the model from the form? 3) Even if you figure out a way for 1 & 2, how would I handle a regular ChoiceField?

Comment: I think we are missing bit context here. What kind of form are you using to display stuff. Choicefields display their own values well enough. Model.get_FOO_display() is meant for rendering model attribute values in template not in forms. If you want to render some fields display value in some place in template, then perhaps this is what you are looking for : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109432/django-choicefield-get-currently-selected

Comment: Yes, that's why I knew immediately that get_FOO_display() doesn't work in my case. On the bright side, the link you provided contained an answer that with some modifications, worked perfectly, so thanks :)

Comment: Can you please share how you did it? I have a similar situation.

Comment: http://timsaylor.com/index.php/2012/05/25/get-the-display-name-of-a-modelchoicefields-selected-value-in-django/

Answer (score 1):

From the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5109986/2891365) that @Odif Yltsaeb provided, I was able to use modify the code from the answer to work generically for my needs. Here's the code for reference:

```
def choiceval(boundfield):
    """
    Get literal value from field's choices. Empty value is returned if value is 
    not selected or invalid.

    Important: choices values must be unicode strings.

        choices=[(u'1', 'One'), (u'2', 'Two')

    Modified from:
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/5109986/2891365
    Originally found from:
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960943/django-rendering-display-value-of-a-modelchoicefield-and-choicefield-in-a-templ
    """
    # Explicitly check if boundfield.data is not None. This allows values such as python "False"
    value = boundfield.data if boundfield.data is not None else boundfield.form.initial.get(boundfield.name)
    if value is None:
        return u''
    if not hasattr(boundfield.field, 'choices'):
        return value
    return dict(boundfield.field.choices).get(value, u'')
```